# Convert Dictionary to a List

Tags: python, dictionary

I am struggling to understand how a dictionary with 2 keys as below works. I am familiar with traditional key:value dictionary but not with the one below. I need to covert a dictionary into a regular dictionary so it looks like `d1 = {1:0.26, 2:0.84, 3:0.71, 4:0.03}`

Thanks everyone for help

```
d1 = {'inds': [1, 2, 3, 4,], 'vals': [0.28, 0.84, 0.71, 0.03]}
```

Comment: hint: you need to use `zip`

Comment: That is a "traditional", "regular" dictionary, with strings as keys and lists as values.

Comment: Your question title does not match your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on python 3 and not legacy python you could simply do this:

```
{i+1: v for i, v in enumerate(d1['vals'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
d2 = {k:v for k,v in zip(d1["inds"],d1["vals"])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop:

```
d1 = {'inds': [1, 2, 3, 4,], 'vals': [0.28, 0.84, 0.71, 0.03]}
keys = d1['inds']
vals = d1['vals']
d2 = {}
for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
    d2[key] = val[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehensions add a layer of unneeded complexity. You can just do this:

```
d1 = {'inds': [1, 2, 3, 4,], 'vals': [0.28, 0.84, 0.71, 0.03]}
result = dict(zip(d1["inds"],d1["vals"]))
print(result)
```

---

```
{1: 0.28, 2: 0.84, 3: 0.71, 4: 0.03}
```

If you are using Python 3.7, you can do this too:

```
result = dict(zip(*d1.values()))
```